# PowerBuilder beginner question

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm working at a company as a entry-level developer.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the PowerBuilder concepts.  Any good tutorials/advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmmm, if I could learn PB all over again, how would I do it?

1. Come to PB with a healthy understanding first of SQL. If your app is hitting a database, PB is very good at that, but not understanding SQL well when I was younger lead to poor decisions. Well written SQL will help you with application partitioning, performance, and centralization of logic. I have found that good use of SQL can significantly reduce the amount of "crufty cobble-on PB client code" that tends to congregate around datawindow code commonly written by less experienced developers.
2. With a good understanding of SQL you should have a healthy understanding of result sets. That's a big part of appreciating the power of the datawindow and datastores. In PB, the datawindow is **everything**. I'd start by using the datawindow simply as a report maker to drive home how it retrieves data, and the power it gives you in graphic presentation control.
3. Develop knowledge of PB script. It's not that hard, but it has some quirks. Learn how to manipulate the datawindow with PB script, how to make it interact with other controls.
4. Sybase offers PB classes. Take one of the fast track courses to get an overview of how to do things in the tool. If your company wants you to learn this but is too cheap to pay for professional training...you may want to reconsider where you work. Investing in employees is what separates the good employers from the mediocre ones.
5. If you understand object orientation, that will help you write a potentially better and easier-to-maintain app. Even if you're in the position of only being able to cobble-on to an existing app (welcome to my world) then future enhancements to that app can be designed to introduce better approaches and fewer complications. You can't fix the old stuff overnight, but you can make sure the new stuff generates less production support than the old stuff; if you can increase the functionality of the app while keeping support needs level, you've won at least a little victory under difficult circumstances.
6. If you're inheriting an existing app, doing production support is a good way to get broad, if random, exposure to the app. If it's a legacy PB app with any age on it, it's probably poorly designed, poorly written, poorly documented, and not very object oriented. Build experience with the app and gain familiarity with it before attempting refactorings; there are probably all kinds of hidden dependencies in it.
   If you are fortunate enough to be starting from scratch, then make a prototype and learn from it what a mess it is to maintain a pile of crap where code is splayed through GUI objects. Be careful to avoid coding around the datawindow's built-in support for concurrency control, and to avoid tons of embedded SQL in the script. Then throw the prototype away and consolidate business logic in PB non-visual objects or even database stored procedures; you want to put reusable business logic in the most centralized place, and that place is not in a button or custom event on a window.

Books and Tutorials

- There aren't many PB books being published these days, but if you're doing classic PB, there is a good [PB9 Advanced Client/Server Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325004) book by Bruce Armstrong.
- The PB manuals have lots of information, and if you are using the Powerbuilder Foundation Class, it has been open sourced. You can get it at Sybase CodeExchange.
- There are some good sites out there. Fellow Stackoverflow user Terry Voth has a [great one](http://www.techno-kitten.com/). I also like Ken Howe's [PB tips site](http://www.pbdr.com).
- There are some PB newsgroups with good information. And other resources too; Google will help you a lot here.
- PowerBuilder Developer's Journal doesn't have as many classic PB tips and examples as it used to but most of the old content I believe may be available online.

Random Things

- I'm hoping your shop uses source control. If not, figure it out and get that going. Then look into PB ORCA Script. I started using this to automate our builds and it's a time saver. There's a chapter in the PB9 Advanced Client/Server book on it, but also some good examples at CodeExchange.
- If you're new and under the gun, you'll probably find yourself many times thinking, "I can get that data easy by slapping in an embedded SQL statement here". Be careful about that; quick hit, single row, retrieve-only queries can be ok, but misuse of embedded SQL in your app makes it hard to maintain.
- If you're new and under the gun, you'll probably find yourself many times thinking, "I can get that data to look the way I want by throwing in some code in the retrieve row or retrieve end events". Be careful about that too. Retrieve row logic will hurt performance. I've seen retrieve end logic often used to do additional processing and add data to the datawindow; this is much better done as part of the datawindow's original SQL statement rather than by adding more cruft to the datawindow control scripts.
- It's not all just about learning PB. Learn your company's business and understand the processes your system is supposed to help with. Sometimes the solution's complexity isn't fixed by automating it with a system, but by getting the authorized parties to recognize that a process can be simplified on the business side first.
- People get so worked up about new languages; I'm not an exception and really want to do more with .Net and others. But it is your commitment as a developer that makes the difference; you can do great things in any language, be it PB or VB or Delphi or .Net. Your constituents don't really know or care what the app is written in if it helps them get work done.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed, I sympathize. There's no question that as powerful a tool as PB is, the classic IDE hasn't kept up with the times and more recent languages are far more robust and feature substantially superior third party and open source support. However, even Sybase recognizes this and the future of PB is .Net, if your company will let you upgrade to that point (and convincing management to move forward rather than backward can be the biggest headache of all).

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed, I can empathize there.  As with any language you need to learn the "ins and outs".  IDE crashes are rare but there are definitely things that happen where there is no experience for... well experience.  Once you finally become comfortable you may find that you have a very powerful tool available for future problems. Even though PB usage has slowed, it is still a leader in productivity, now this statement is of course opinion but it's the opinion of a developer who has used many tools and languages.

Comment: @Sayem, I'm happy that things worked out for you. PowerBuilder isn't easy to learn and be proficient.  I enjoy Java myself but I decided to stay away from Java because of the track record of projects I've witnessed while consulting at many Fortune 100 companies. Most were scrapped after going severely over budget, few made it to production always over budget and almost always having a user group dissatisfied with the deliverable.  In the same time-frame I've worked on dozens of "legacy" PowerBuilder applications that have become mission critical and deemed to risky/expensive to convert.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed, rebooting your machine every day can do wonders for PowerBuilder's stability. During the day, if PB seems the least bit flaky, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

PB just takes time. It is OO so you have an easier time getting it to work for you if you have these concept down. if not GET THEM DOWN. it will make understanding the whole programming side of the product easier.

As far as the IDE ans so forth goes, you will get used to the quirks in time. always consult the internet if something strange is happening, we have seen just about everything that can happen so far, somebody has. if you can find a copy of advanced Powerbuilder 7.0 from McGraw i think it will have a good grounding int he concepts  going forward, the 9 book recommended is great as well. also try to get you head around the PFC, many shops use it and will continue. it has many powerful services, RowSelection, Linkage, etc. that will make life soooo much easier for you.

Just stay calm when trouble hits and ask a lot of questions if needed of the community.

Good Luck!